# msal-react access token vs id token different expirations time

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, msal-react

For authentication, in my application I use the @azure/msal-react library and @azure/msal-browser.
I have noticed that the method that downloads the token acquireTokenSilent() returns both: accessToken and idToken, while the expiration time of these tokens is different each time I try to download, the difference is never the same or similar. And the token itself is refreshed only when it reaches the acesss token's expiration time.
Is this a natural behavior or what could be the reasons for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a natural behavior that the [id token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#id-token-lifetime)'s lifetime is 1 hour by default while the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#access-token-lifetime) have 60-90 minutes (75 minutes on average) by default. Microsoft official document mentioned it.

And certainly, lifetime of the token can be changed by setting [token lifetime policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policies-for-access-saml-and-id-tokens). Here's the steps for [setting token lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes).